# partially reversing listitems with jQuery

Tags: jquery, reverse, html-lists

I'm making an abacus with 10 beads in it. When a bead is clicked that bead and all the beads before it are arranged left in the abacus, and the remaining beads are moved to the right in the abacus.

The list:

```
<ul class="abacus">
    <li class="bead">1</li>
    <li class="bead">2</li>
    <li class="bead">3</li>
    <li class="bead">4</li>
    <li class="bead">5</li>
    <li class="bead">6</li>
    <li class="bead selected">7</li>
    <li class="bead off">8</li>
    <li class="bead off">9</li>
    <li class="bead off">10</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
li.bead {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 28px;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
}

/* just for visuals: */
li.bead.selected {
    background-image: url('../images/smartie-selected.png');
}

li.bead.off {
    float: right;
    background-image: url('../images/smartie-unselect.png');
}
```

Because the 'off' beads are floating to the right, their order has to be reversed (otherwise the abacus will look like: [1][2][3][4][5][6][7]--------[10][9][8]).

The jQuery I'm using for this is:

```
$("li.bead").click(function() {
    // remove the 'selected' class of the previously selected bead (just for visuals):
    $("li.bead.selected").removeClass("selected");

    // save the number of the bead was selected:
    var no = Number($(this).html());

    // add the 'selected' class to the clicked bead (just for visuals):
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    // add the 'off' class to all the 'higher' beads than the selected one 
    // and removing that class for all he lower beads:
    $(this).parent().children().each(function() {
        if(Number($(this).html()) > no) {
            $(this).addClass('off');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('off');
        }
    });

    // reverse all beads:
    $(this).parent().children().each(function(i, li) {
        $(this).parent().prepend(li);
    });             
});
```

So, the last step in that jQuery reverses all beads, which correctly arranges the 'off'-beads, but also reverses the other beads, making the abacus look like, for instance:

[4][3][2][1]------------[5][6][7][8][9][10]

What should I add to only reverse the first beads back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would aim to avoid the float. First I would try adding a margin-right value to the selected element. Something like this...

```
$("li.bead").click(function() {
    // remove the 'selected' class of the previously selected bead (just for visuals):
    $("li.bead.selected").removeClass("selected");
    $("li.bead.off").removeClass("off");

    // save the number of the bead was selected:
    var no = Number($(this).html());

    // add the 'selected' class to the clicked bead (just for visuals):
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    // add the 'off' class to all the 'higher' beads than the selected one
    $(this).nextAll().addClass("off");         
});
```

and CSS...

```
li.bead {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 28px;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
}

/* just for visuals: */
li.bead.selected {
    margin-right:100px;/*change this to suit your design*/
    background-image: url('../images/smartie-selected.png');
}

li.bead.off {
    background-image: url('../images/smartie-unselect.png');
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/DXzKQ/)

if you need the right margin to be dynamic you could always calculate it in javascript and add it to the selected element, something like...

```
var parent = $(this).parent();
var margin = parent .width() - (parent.children().length * $(this).width());
parent.children().css("margin-right", "0px");//clear other margins
$(this).css("margin-right", margin + "px");//set this margin
```

Comment: This is going to space each selected bead with 100px rather than the set of beads then the javascript is going to line them up correctly and not seperate them isnt it?

Comment: @JackalopeZero: I believe only one bead can have the "selected" class at a time (the currently clicked one)

Comment: very smart..! while shifting last bead from left to right, I need to click second last bead. why so ?

Comment: It works - the only thing I had to add was `$(this).prevAll().removeClass("off");` because it wouldn't work if you'd click an 'off' bead. Great solution, way more elegant than the floating!

Comment: @Umesh: This is the nature of an abacus, if you click bead 9 it means you want to select 9 on the left (and the remainder 1 should move to the right)

Comment: @ReinoudSchuijers: My current code works with off bead clicking, perhaps you copied my code before I made my edit. Either way, your suggestion is just a good ;)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set up an example, i've never used an abacus (im not that old!) and i cant say i really understand where the problem is. But at a guess i'd say have a look at jquery's

```
nextAll()
prevAll()
```

methods as that will allow you to state only the beads AFTER or BEFORE the selected bead .. which i believe is what you need to do ?

Comment: As the correct answer shows, the `nextAll()` and `prevAll()` methods are indeed part of the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$(this).parent().children().each(function() {
        if(Number($(this).html()) > no) {
            $(this).addClass('off');
            $(this).parent().prepend(li);

        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('off');
            $(this).parent().append(li);

        }
    });
```